# Windows 7 x64 not returning search results from Outlook 2010 x86

Tags: windows-7, 32bit-64bit, outlook-2010

We're working on upgrading our office PCs to Windows 7 and Office 2010. At this time, I'm planning on deploying 64-bit Windows where possible to take advantage of the 4GB of RAM several PCs have. Office 2010 deployment is 32-bit at Microsoft's recommendation and to avoid problems with any Office add-ons.

I'm finding that Windows 7 x64 machines do not return search results from within Outlook. Am I missing something? Searching online reveals many others experiencing the same problems, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Has anyone else encountered and overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the Customize Start Menu windo (Right-click Start Button, choose Properties, click Customize... on the Start Menu tab) make sure `Do Not Search` is NOT selected under the `Search other files and libraries` heading.  See if that does it for you.

**EDIT:**
Also, make sure indexing is turned on for your mailbox in Outlook's Search Options.  In the little drop-down in the Search box in Outlook choose Search Options and make sure your mailbox is checked.  Outlook will need a restart, and then you'll have to wait for indexing to complete before you are able to get any results.

Comment: Thanks Squillman, but this setting for "Search other files and libraries" is already set to "Search with public folders". This is identical to my Windows 7 x86 with Outlook 2010 x86 machine.

Comment: @Punch See me edit, got another thing for you to look at